# .NET Core 1.0 equivalent for System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard, .net-core-rc2

What would be (the closest) .NET Core 1.0 equivalent for

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
```

?

**update**

As @svick clarified *System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId* is at its usual location. Please see the screenshot below. The question is closed. (Still unclear how and when CurrentThread property's *System.Threading.Thread* instance is initialized to a non-null value (*default(System.Threading.Thread)* is always == null?) but this is not the subject of this topic.)

[image]

**update 2**

Actually *System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId* is available in .NET Core 1.0 application project, which has defined in its project.json:

```
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
  "imports": "dnxcore50"
}
```

and is missing in .NET Core 1.0 class library project, which has defined in its project.json:

```
"frameworks": {
  "netstandard1.6": {
   "imports": "dnxcore50"
}
```

How to make *System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId* available in .NET Core 1.0 class library project?

Comment: What you're looking at is the source of the reference assembly (that's why it's in the `ref` directory and not in `src`). [The actual implementation is in CoreCLR.](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/release/1.0.0/src/mscorlib/src/System/Threading/Thread.cs#L751-L758)

Comment: @svick: Thank you, I see it now - ManagedThreadId is implemented using native mode hacking - here is a quoted comment from thread.cs code: "_The base implementation of Thread is all native.  The following fields should never be used in the C# code.  They are here to define the proper space so the thread object may be allocated.  DON'T CHANGE THESE UNLESS YOU MODIFY ThreadBaseObject in vm\object.h_"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's still the same: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`.

The `Thread` class is in the `System.Threading.Thread` package, which is included in `Microsoft.NETCore.App`, but not in `NETStandard.Library`. This means that `Thread` will work out of the box in a .Net Core application, but to use it in a .Net Core library, you need to add `"System.Threading.Thread": "4.0.0"` to `"dependencies"` in your project.json.

For VS 2017 and .csproj based .NET Core projects, you'd add it to the .csproj:

```
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Thread" Version="4.0.0" />
```

Comment: Silly me. Yes, I have just started to use .NET Core 1.0 yesterday and I have missed System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId. I will update and I will close my original question.

Comment: I have added *update2* clarifying the context of the subject question/issue: question is set back to open

Comment: Yes, adding  `"System.Threading.Thread": "4.0.0"` to the `dependencies` section of the `project.json` file solves the subject issue.

Comment: OT: (should I ask the following question separately, will it be accepted at StackOverflow?) 

Where can I find detailed description of what is included in `Microsoft.NETCore.App` and what is included in `NETStandard.Library`? - I wanted to convert my generic/utility .NET Framework 4.0 compatible class library, web service and console application to .NETCore 1.0 to have them running under both MS Windows and Linux. I wanted to keep my current development/conversion in VS2015 but then port the project under VSCode. I don't see on the web any tutorials.

Comment: @ShamilS Yeah, I think asking a new question would be the best option, comments are not meant for that.

Comment: OK, it looks like my question has already been posted and has been answered here ".NET Core - solutions, frameworks, imports, runtimes" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585898/net-core-solutions-frameworks-imports-runtimes)